# Physical situation corresponding to a compactly supported curvature tensor?

Tags: general-relativity

Consider the Minkowski spacetime $(\Bbb R^4,\eta)$, and take some $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb R^4)$. Then the metric 
$$g=\eta+\mathrm df\otimes\mathrm df$$
has a compactly supported Riemann tensor (assume |$\mathrm df$| is small enough so that $g$ is Lorentian). What would be a physical situation corresponding to such a metric with $C_0$ curvature?

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction is to say that the positive energy theorem should tell you that this does not happen in any realistic situation.

Comment: @Danu That's a good point, so the DEC must be violated. I'm not too surprised by that, since the energy-momentum is "trapped" in the timelike direction.

Comment: Could you please cite some reference showing that Riemann is compactly supported?

Comment: @magma $g=\eta$ outside of a compact set.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning of $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb R^4)$. I am not familiar with this notation. I know what is $C^\infty$ though, if that matters.

Comment: @magma https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425758/space-of-smooth-functions-with-compact-support